# How can I add a script to a Windows path on GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to add a script to the path on GitHub Actions, using bash shell. Nothing has worked so far. The script is a single file and I don't mind where it goes.

Previous failures:

```bash
mkdir -p "$HOME/.local/bin"
cp -R latexdiff "$HOME/.local/bin"
echo "$HOME/.local/bin/latexdiff" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

and:

```bash
cp -R latexdiff "/c/Program Files/"
echo "C:\Program Files\latexdiff" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

Comment: You don't have to copy it first. Just add its path. That should work in subsequent steps.

Comment: Subsequent steps modify the location where it downloads to, so that won't work. Anyway, given that when I do copy it, it doesn't work, why not?

Comment: Are you trying to execute it in the same step after setting it?

Comment: No, and I can't.

Comment: Have you verified if the `PATH` env var is set correctly? The location should not be an issue.

Comment: Indeed, the PATH is not getting set. If I do e.g. "echo $PATH | grep latexdiff", the step errors with exit code 1, i.e. grep not found.

Comment: Mm, but if I test $PATH in a *subsequent* step, then it's found.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior. It's only visible to the subsequent steps in the same job.

Comment: Sure, no problem. So, what was the issue? Your complete workflow might've given it away already but it's not included in your question.

Comment: I think indeed my test was failing. My PATH was updated but I didn't see it. Now I have another problem...! Thanks for your help.